# How to call CCK as block?

Tags: blocks, entities

Actually I created user's request mail form as CCK.This CCK displayed page name as node/add/laptoprepair.I want to display this CCK page as Block for the purpose of calling multiple page.How to create this CCK as block?

[image: Created content types]

In user's  page it is displayed as,
[image]

Comment: Did you even bother to search google? http://bit.ly/1DoAvxD

Answer (score 1):

Please refer these modules, would be helpful

[nodesinblock](http://www.drupal.org/project/nodesinblock) and [nodeblock](http://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock)